# Limitations of the Network Monitor

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

What is the reason Flash Builder 4's Network Monitor does not support applications that were created using pure ActionScript and Library projects? It seems to work only for Flex projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Network Monitorseems to work only with the Services: HTTPService, etc. It does not work with URLRequest.

Try Charles or BURP proxy sniffers; they are worth the time and money.

Comment: Thx Richard, I've used Charles many years ago. Loved it. Loved Flash Builder more when it had integrated sniffer but less love now cause it can't do everything.